# Inheritance and generics in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, dbcontext

I have the following base repository:

```cs
public abstract class BaseRepository<TEntity, TContext> : IBaseRepository<TEntity>
    where TEntity : class
    where TContext : ApplicationDbContext
{
    // save, add, ...
}
```

Where `IBaseRepository` contains the basic CRUD operations.

My `ApplicationDbContext` is:

```cs
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<IdentityUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }
    
    // entities here
}
```

And finally, `AuditableIdentityContext` is used for auditing some tables:

```cs
public abstract class AuditableIdentityContext : ApplicationDbContext
{
    public AuditableIdentityContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options) : base(options)
    {
    }

    public virtual async Task<int> SaveChangesAsync(string userId)
    {
        // writing to audit log here
        OnBeforeSaveChanges(userId);
        var result = await base.SaveChangesAsync();
        return result;
    }
```

From the repository, I can't access the auditable save method:

```cs
public class MyRepo : BaseRepository<MyEntity, AuditableIdentityContext>, IMyRepo 
{
    public MyRepo(AuditableIdentityContext context) : base(context)
    {
    }
}
```

Now

```cs
_myRepo.SaveChangesAsync("123"); // not found
```

Why I can't access the inherited method from the child class?

Comment: Your `SaveChangesAsync` method is on `AuditableIdentityContext`, but `_myRepo` is presumably of type `MyRepo`. That line doesn't work because you defined the method on one type, but you're attempting to call it on a different, unrelated type

Comment: If you'd just searched on the words "dbcontext" and "repository pattern" you'll find plenty of results almost all of the opinion that you shouldn't use the repository pattern with a dbcontext.

Comment: `MyRepo` inherits from `BaseRepository<...>`, it does not inherit from `MyEntity` or `AuditableIdentityContext`. Those are merely used as generic parameters to close the `BaseRepository<...>` generic type.

Comment: Thank you. @Damien_The_Unbeliever So using repository pattern with a dbcontext is basically mean that I shouldn't have `where TContext : ApplicationDbContext` in the base repository? It should be injected instead?

Comment: @MuhammadJabarin no it just means that composition and inheritance are different. You should constrain `TContext` if you need to it to be of a specific type, i.e. to call methods on it that are declared by that type. But constraining `TContext` in `class BaseRepository<TContext> where TContext: SomeType` doesn't mean that a `BaseRepository<SomeType>`  is a `SomeType`.

Answer (score 0):

```
public abstract class BaseRepository<TEntity, TContext> : IBaseRepository<TEntity>
    where TEntity : class
    where TContext : ApplicationDbContext
{
    protected readonly TContext _dbContext;

    protected BaseRepository(TContext dbContext)
    {
        _dbContext = dbContext;
    }
}    

public class MyRepo : BaseRepository<MyEntity, AuditableIdentityContext>, IMyRepo 
{
    public MyRepo(AuditableIdentityContext context) : base(context)
    {
    }

    public async Task<int> SaveChangesAsync(string userId)
    {
           return await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync(userId);
    }
 }
```